# Flatten javascript array of objects with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have a javascript array of object that looks like this:

```
"partners":[{"username":"fangonk","profileImg":"fangonk.jpg"},
            {"username":"jane","profileImg":"jane.jpg"},
            {"username":"tom_jones","profileImg":"tom.jpg"}]
```

I would like to output the value of each array's key using the underscore library. So for each object, I'd like to output something that looks like this:

```
<h1>Username Value</h1><img src="profileImg Value here" />
```

Comment: Ooops - tired brain. Fixed.

Comment: What should the resulting array look like?

Comment: With a `.map()` function, typically you'd have the callback return a value and then store the return value of the `.map()` call, which will be a new Array of whatever your function returned.

Comment: That's not how you print values from an array or an object.

Comment: Ok, I can see that I was going about outputting the values in a weird  way. I've restructured my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit confused about your "source", but I think you're just trying to do this:

```
_.each(partners, function(p) { document.write('<h1>' + p.username + '</h1>\
  <img src="' + p.profileImg + '" alt="' + p.username + '" />'); }
//substitute some DOM method (e.g. jquery().append) for document.write
```

Is this the result you're looking for?

this would only be applicable if your source looked more like:

```
var partners = [{"username":"fangonk","profileImg":"fangonk.jpg"},
                {"username":"jane","profileImg":"jane.jpg"},
                {"username":"tom_jones","profileImg":"tom.jpg"}];
```

EDIT:

```
var someBiggerObject = { 
  partners: [
    {"username":"fangonk","profileImg":"fangonk.jpg"},
    {"username":"jane","profileImg":"jane.jpg"},
    {"username":"tom_jones","profileImg":"tom.jpg"}
  ]
};

_.each(someBiggerObject.partners, function(p) { document.write('<h1>' + p.username + '</h1>\
  <img src="' + p.profileImg + '" alt="' + p.username + '" />'); }
//substitute some DOM method (e.g. jquery().append) for document.write
```

Comment: The partners array is an attribute in a larger JSON object, so restructuring it could be difficult. Is there anyway to accomplish what I am looking for? Is there a way to restructure with underscore first?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is _.template

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kqvzB)

If your structure is like this:

```
var list = {"partners":[ 
    {"username":"fangonk","profileImg":"fangonk.jpg"},
    {"username":"jane","profileImg":"jane.jpg"},
    {"username":"tom_jones","profileImg":"tom.jpg"}
]};
```

You can create the repeated item template (note `type="text/html"`)

```
<script type="text/html" id="userItemTemplate">
    <h1><%= username %></h1><img src='<%= profileImg %>' />
</script>
```

and put each item into the template via a loop

```
var uIT = $("#userItemTemplate").html();
_.each(list.partners,function(user){
    $("#target").append(_.template(uIT,user));        
});
```

**OR**

put the loop into your template

```
<script type="text/html" id="userTemplate">
    <% _.each(partners,function(user,key,list){ %>
    <h1><%= user.username %></h1><img src='<%= user.profileImg %>' />
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

then push the whole array in

```
var uT = $("#userTemplate").html();
$("#target2").html(_.template(uT,list));
```

Note that I am using lodash instead of underscore. It's compatible for the most part, but I prefer lodash because the benchmarks are faster and the library is maintained well.